# Can we add a claim in WSO2 Identity Server to have a unique value?

Tags: claims-based-identity, wso2-identity-server

I have a user profile which is identified in WSO2 Identity Server by it's unique username and unique contact id. WSO2 already supports unique usernames but I also want to ensure that we won't have any duplicate contact ids assigned.

Is there a way that we can support uniqueness for claims other than the username?

Comment: There is no out of the box way to do this AFAIK via a configuration. A workaround I can think is to write a listener that gets triggered during a profile update and can validate whether the updated unique contact id is valid. Will that work for you?

Comment: But will that listener work if I am trying to invoke admin services of WSO2 IS  to add a user with it's claims?

Comment: Yeah. It is something that will be triggered at user store level. So when you add a user in any way be it admin service or SCIM API, at the lowest level it will be adding claims to userstores. At that point this listener will be triggered.

Comment: Which IS version are you planning to use?

Comment: The latest one, 5.3.0

Comment: Thank you for  sharing with me a potential solution.

Comment: Posted the approach as an answer for future benefit of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to do this AFAIK via a configuration.

An alternate approach I can think of is to write a user operation listener that gets triggered during a profile update and can validate whether the updated unique contact id is valid.

Refer http://www.securityinternal.com/2016/08/writing-user-operation-event-listener.html to get an understanding on how to write one.